# How to sort a list without mutating it

Tags: java, sorting

I would like to sort a `List` of items in Java and have the sort return a new sorted `List` without mutating the original `List`. Is there a commonly used library that does this?

Comment: All Java SE collection classes have a constructor that copies another collection.  Using that, you can do `List<Item> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(unsortedList); sortedList.sort(null);`

Comment: 1) Copy it, sort the copy, or 2) `stream()` it, sort the `Stream`. Perhaps 3) create a sorted _view_ - but that would have `O(lg n)` access times, so probably not useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 or higher, you can use the Stream API. See [Sorting a list with stream.sorted() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517977/sorting-a-list-with-stream-sorted-in-java) for details.

For example:

```
List<String> sortedList = myList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

This copies (by reference) the elements in the original list to the new list. Making changes like the ordering of one list won't affect the other.

```
List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newList = new ArrayList(originalList);
```

Please note if you modify the objects that are in the list however, the changes will be reflected in both lists since objects are copied by reference.