# How to swap two SubLists from ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, sublist

```
var numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

This is a series of numbers (just for example)
But, it starts with the wrong number.
I need it to start with **21**, not **1**.
Modifying the cycle would be unnecessarily complex. It is easier to divide the `ArrayList` into two `List` and swap them.

```
numbers = Stream.concat(numbers.subList(20, 100).stream(), numbers.subList(0, 20).stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

I used the `concat` method, which merges two `ArrayLists` and `subList` method, which returns a part of the `ArrayList`.

However, it is illogical to create a new `ArrayList` that is only differently ordered.

It would be enough to use the [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) method, but I don't know how to write it to sort it correctly.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: I cannot make any sense of your Question. If you want loop to start at 21, change `i = 1` to `i = 21`. If you want to split an ArrayList, that has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. If you want to sort the List, that too has been covered many many times already. But I have no idea *what* you really want.  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Why the JavaFX tag?

Comment: Duplicate: [*Sorting a list with stream.sorted*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517977/sorting-a-list-with-stream-sorted-in-java)

Comment: @Basil Bourque I deleted the tag. Yes, you are right. I just didn't know what to look for. Only when writing the question did I realize that I should use the `sorted` method. However, the @Udith Gunaratna user stated exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in sorting comparator, you get 2 numbers (let's say `n1` and `n2`), and based on the return value, they will be ordered.

- If a negative value is returned, `n1` is ordered before `n2`
- If a positive value is returned, `n2` is ordered before `n1`
- If `0` is returned, both are considered equal in order

Keeping this in mind, you can write the sorting comparator to provide the following behavior.

- If both `n1` and `n2` are in the same region (either between `0-19` or `20-100`), sort them as usual
- If `n1` and `n2` are in different regions, order the number belongs to the `20-100` (which will be the larger number of the two) before the other one

Example code,

```
numbers =
    (ArrayList<Integer>)
            numbers.stream()
                    .sorted((n1, n2) -> {
                        if (((n1 >= 21) && (n2 >= 21)) || ((n1 <= 20) && (n2 <= 20))) {
                            return  n1 - n2;
                        } else {
                            return n2 - n1;
                        }
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot.