# Java sorting a Collection in functional style

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability

I am learning Java and while trying to sort an ArrayList of objects I found this way of doing it.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
al.add("Friends"); 
al.add("Dear"); 
al.add("Is"); 
al.add("Superb"); 

Collections.sort(al); 

System.out.println("List after the use of" + 
                       " Collection.sort() :\n" + al);
```

This method works but since I come from a functional programming background I was wondering what are the most elegant ways to do sorting on a collection in Java in functional style (so by returning a new collection and not by modifying the original one).

Comment: Maybe if you use the [stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517977/sorting-a-list-with-stream-sorted-in-java) you can do it that way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517977/sorting-a-list-with-stream-sorted-in-java

Comment: Java 8 streams is what you are after: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: thanks to everyone who answered,the stream API seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: Why not wrap copying the list plus sorting the copy into your own method? If the language/framework you're using doesn't quite match the language you want to use for expressing your program, create the missing parts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not like Collections.sort() where the parameter reference gets sorted. In this case you just get a sorted stream that you need to collect and assign to another variable eventually:

```
List result = al.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or :

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
al.add("Friends"); 
al.add("Dear"); 
al.add("Is"); 
al.add("Superb"); 

System.out.println(al);
al.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
System.out.println(al);
```